# Why do Traffic to Data Sources metrics only selectively show certain sites in Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to understand why several of my display metrics in Tableau Server only show certain sites and not all of them. I'm having this problem specifically with the "Traffic to Data Sources" display. I should have more sites but I only have one or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a time range filter that Tableau applies automatically. The default is 7 days. This could be one reason. You can also verify usage using the traffic to views tab. There should be correlation between the sites you see on both reports.

If you don't have the same sites on traffic to views and data sources, I would suspect there is an issue. If you don't see traffic in views or data sources, I would suspect that you don't have the traffic you are expecting. You can verify traffic by doing some navigating then checking the traffic reports again and looking for your own actions. You can also check traffic more efficiently with the back end WORKGROUP database. See this [guide](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm) to get started.

Comment: Thanks @vizyourdata. I definitely think I have an issue then. This might seem silly to ask but would the Traffic to Data Sources only coves external data sources and not local sources such as spreadsheets?

Comment: @xorLogic this should be representing all data sources as far as I know. Looking into my report shows known extracts and live data sources.